# which collection is best to store key value pair but i have to perform search for both key & for value

Tags: java, search, collections

I have two properties Name & phone Number.My requirement is, User can search based on any property and the result should be Name & Phone Number.

**case 1.** IF user search based on Name,It should get Name and phone Number.

**case 2.** If user search based on Phone Number,It should get Name and phone Number..

Please tell me,Which collection is best for this scenario.

Comment: [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) maybe?

Comment: @NikosM.: You need multiple of them. Each mapping from one key to the object containing all data.

Comment: @fabian, hmm i see did not read question thoroughly

Comment: How do you handle 1-to-many relationships? E.g. Home or Office line?

Answer (score 3):

You may use [BiMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html). It's a part of [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) project.

A bidirectional map, is a map that preserves the uniqueness of its values as well as that of its keys. This allows an inverse view which maps each of this bimap's values to its associated key. Guava has mutliple implementation types such as HashBiMap, ImmutableBiMap, EnumBiMap and EnumHashBiMap.

You may have a look at the [link](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/guava-bimap-example/).

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.List Interface extends the Collection interface.
The List interface declares methods for managing an ordered collection of object (a sequence). You can:

- Control where each element is inserted in the list
- Access elements by their integer index (position in the list)
- Search for elements in the list
- Insert duplicate elements and null values, in most List
  implementations

Especially if you’re dynamically resizing a collection of object, favor using a List over a Java array.
Some additional methods provided by List include:

- add(int index, E element) — Insert an element at a specific location
  (without an index argument, new elements are appended to the end)
- get(int index) — Return an element at the specified location

  remove(int index) — Remove an element at the specified location
- set(int index, E element) — Replace the element at the specified
  location
- subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) — Returns as a List a modifiable
  view of the specified portion of the list (that is, changes to the
  view actually affect the underlying list)

Classes Implementing List:
Java provides several classes that implement the List interface.
Two are used most commonly:

- java.util.ArrayList

An ArrayList is usually your best bet for a List if the values remain fairly static once you’ve created the list. It’s more efficient than a LinkedList for random access.

- java.util.LinkedList

A LinkedList provides better performance than an ArrayList if you’re frequently inserting and deleting elements, especially from the middle of the collection. But it’s slower than an ArrayList for random-access.
In the following example, notice the use of the java.util.Collections.sort() static method, which does an in-place sort of the elements in a List:
package util;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This program reads arguments passed to it from the command-line
 * or the lines from STDIN, sorts them, and writes the result to STDOUT.
 */
public class Sort {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            Arrays.sort(args);
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(args[i]);
            }
        } else {
            List lines = new ArrayList();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
            Collections.sort(lines);
            for (Iterator i = lines.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
                System.out.println(i.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A long post... but unfortuantely search on `List`s isn't efficient.

Comment: True, though it is native to Java. I guess if you don't mind extending with that guava project then fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/bidimap/package-summary.html) from Apache Commons.

But these maps will prevent a 1-to-many relationships.  It's not clear if that's required ( E.g. Office lines, landlines, etc. )

Also, does the entire map fit in memory?  Do you have to store it on disk between runs?

If so, I'd recommend a map backed by [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/).  This can give a [Serialized BidiMap](https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/blob/master/src/test/java/examples/Bidi_Map.java).  The nice side-effect to that approach is that you can store the same value under multiple keys if you'd like to.